# It isn't very easy to read DeepMind's "mind", is it?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, experimental-physics, soft-question

Recently the DeepMind supercomputer achieved the ability to predict protein structures to a pretty commendable level of accuracy.

To get "*insight*" from any physical phenomena, experiment must be able to codify a law that can be used to reproduce future experiments. But when an "*Artificial intelligence*" (AI) comes in the way, we get into a spot of bother because we would need to probe the "mind" of the observer, in the sense that there is an added layer of uncertainty faced by a theoretical physicist in trying to disentangle the probabilistic outcomes from the computer. This raises doubt on the reproducibility of an experiment and our understanding of a phenomenon, for example in the protein folding problem, the predicted outcome was amazingly accurate, yet we haven't really been able to reason out complex higher order interactions and energy distributions that occurs within a protein to give its characteristic structure.

Hence, are there any **established** methods to actually scourge out reasoning behind AI systems' functioning in physics problems that **guarantees** reproducibility?

Comment: You mention that the answers are mostly probabilistic. Aren't they completely probabilistic? This is an honest question, I really don't know about AI.

Comment: Why is there an added layer of uncertainty?

Comment: I was thinking that the experiments we perform itself have several limitations. Now if we use "AI" to reason physics, we would need to reason out why the AI system reached the conclusion it reached, which sort of beats the point of using it in the first place?

Comment: I think I see where you're heading with that. Yes, I'd agree. On those occasions when you want to know what an AI is thinking at a deeper level, with an intuitive explanation of its reasoning, that's hard to come by. You're posing an important question that doesn't have any satisfying answers at the moment, though there are some people grappling with it. Sherry Turkle at MIT, for example. If you aren't familiar with her, check her out. And keep asking good questions like this; an AI future is inevitable, so we need to be vigilant about it.

Comment: It does not inspire hope that people making AI generally have the attitude of "let's make it and then figure out the ethical implications." Just making silicon nukes

Comment: Well the point I hoped to make in the question is for clarifying how do scientists deal with interpreting AI related outputs, which seems to be brushed aside in present discourse for the sheer vanity of the tech.

Comment: This is a good question and an active area of research: https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.03474

However, I am not sufficiently informed to say much beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as reading DeepMind's mind, or any other AI for that matter, especially ML (machine learning) based AIs like DeepMind, it's beyond uneasy. It's impossible. It's the nature of the way they're constructed. For example, consider another ML based AI created by Google: AlphaGo. The Google engineers who made AlphaGo are barely amateur Go players themselves. Some of them might barely know how to play at all. So they don't teach it play Go; they let it loose on a surfeit of game data and let the machine sort it out for themselves. The end result is that the machine can become a brilliant player, orders of magnitude beyond the best player among the engineers who constructed it, and yet entirely useless for explaining even the simplest aspect of their own strategy.

So you're right, it's not easy to read its mind because it can't even read its own mind. It doesn't have the mysterious gift of human sentience/consciousness. (Berkeley philosopher John Searle gave a fantastic Google talk about this.)

Check out the incredible documentary on Netflix, "AlphaGo - The Movie," and you'll see: AlphaGo can beat a human to become the world champion Go player; only a human being like Lee Sodol can weep upon being unseated as world champion. AIs can't do that (yet).

Comment: Even better: AlphaZero, a later rendition, was only given the rules of the game. It had no prior knowledge of existing games played by humans, and it learned to play chess, shogi and Go simply by *playing against itself* millions of times

Comment: In the case of AlphaZero we can indeed understand its moves and learn a lot about chess from it.

Comment: 1. It is very different to say that we have not found a way to interpret the 'learning' of neural networks and that it is *impossible.* IMO, this is way too strong a statement to be presented without justification.

Comment: 2. Note that John Searle believes that any computer, even one that could fully explain itself, pass the Turing test, etc., would not be a conscious entity in the same way as a human.

Comment: @b-brekke We can learn *chess* from studying the moves it makes, just as we can learn it from studying grandmaster games (without even talking to grandmasters). The same is true about AlphaGo. But we have very little idea how the program makes its own decisions in either case.